# Update [(ngModel)] on jquery plugin event

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

Is there any way to refresh ngModel on jquery event e.g.

1. datetimepicker on 'dp.change' event.
2. Select2 on select change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like that. It works for me.

In html template

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [listItem]="list" autocomplete id="txtbox" name="txtbox" placeholder="myplaceholder" [(ngModel)]="myModel">
```

In typescript code

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $;
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][autocomplete]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class Autocomplete {
  @Input() listItem: any = [];
  constructor(public _elementRef: ElementRef, private ngModel: NgModel) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let that = this;
    $(this._elementRef.nativeElement).typeahead({
      source: this.listItem.map(item => {
        return { id: item.account.toString(), name: item.account.toString() };
      })
    });

    this.ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe(function(value) {
      /* Set any value of your custom control */
      $(this._elementRef.nativeElement).data("newValue", value);
    });

    /* Inform ng model for any new change happened */
    $(this._elementRef.nativeElement).bind("change", ()=>{
      that.ngModel.update.emit($(that._elementRef.nativeElement).val());
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same plugin and this is how I refresh the model.

```
angular.element('#datetimepicker_id').on('dp.change', function(e){  $scope.date_model = angular.element('#datetimepicker_id').data('date'); });
```

Hope this helps.